# Want to allow inserting html into textarea, but hide html formatting when showing a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a simple CMS, and I want the admin to be able to insert HTML into the textarea and save the article to the db.

And when I display the article, I want to render the html markup/formatting for the article.

BUT, when I am showing a summary of articles, I show the title and a little blurb, how can I escape the HTML formatting in the article body when showing a summary?

I am currently doing:

```
<%= trim(article.body, :length => 100) %>
```

I tried adding `h` but that didn't work?

Comment: Is there a solution to that question?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using rails 3?

If so, `h` is applied by default now, so use `.html_safe` to get unescaped text.
See here: http://markconnell.co.uk/posts/2010/02/rails-3-html-escaping

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags` might help as it did in my case.

```
<%= trim(strip_tags(article.body), :length => 100) %>
```

Answer (score -2):

***Try using Javascript's InnerHTML function***
    < script>
    function change(){
            document.getElementById("Show_Results").innerHTML = "here is html;
    }
    < /script>
    < p onclick="change()" id="Show_Reults">Hey